# Mobile pixel dimension (using Chrome emulator)

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile

I'm developing a mobile template and I set css dimensions in pixel. So I see this:
[image]

the screen width is 980px and the 100% width DIV is 980px; it's reasonable.

But when I see sites on web I see something like this:

[image]

Now chrome tells me that the pixels are 495, how is it possible?
Obviously chrome settings are the same of the previous example....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the ruler guideline along the top of the browser ion your first example, although you've set the dimensions of the emulator to 495px, your mobile template is still rendering at 980px...

This could be due to the absence of a viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It could also be due to a lack of media queries? Without seeing your code, it's hard to know...

Comment: That's right, thank you!